# Help proving $9^n-8n-1$ is divisible by $8$ for all $n > 1$ by induction

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility

I have been trying to prove that  $9^n-8n-1$ is divisible by $8$  for all $n$ integers greater than 1. My progress:
Let $n = 2$. This gives us the expression equal to $64$ which is a factor of 8. Now assume it is true for $n=k$ . for $n = k+1$ :

$$ 9^{k+1} - 8(k+1) - 1$$
$$ = (8+1)^{k} \times (8+1) -8k - 8 -1 $$

I keep getting stuck on this part. Can someone please hint me how I can proceed by using **INDUCTION** only?

Comment: Totally similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996049/proof-by-induction-that-16-mid-5n-4n-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966625/prove-by-induction-64-mid-72n-16n-−-1, and others. My rant about these still stands...

Comment: just do it directly: $8|8n$ and $8|9^n-1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$9^{k+1} - 8(k+1) - 1 = 9(9^k - 8k - 1) + (64k + 8)$

See what to do now?

Comment: I'm not sure why you took out $9$ as a common factor and not $8$

Comment: We want to show that $9^k - 8k - 1$ being divisible by $8$--the inductive hypothesis--implies $9(9^k - 8k - 1) + (64k + 8)$ is divisible by $8$. Now, the inductive hypothesis implies that $9(9^k - 8k - 1)$ is divisible by $8$ and so therefore is $9(9^k - 8k - 1) + (64k + 8) = 9(9^k - 8k - 1) + 8(8k + 1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$9^{k+1}-8(k+1)-1=8\cdot9^k+9^k-8k-8-1=8(9^k-1)+9^k-8k-1$

Answer (score 2):

Assume $9^k -8k -1 $ is divisible of 8.
Then $$9^{k+1}-8(k+1)-1\equiv 1^{k+1}-0(k+1)-1\equiv1-0-1\equiv 0\pmod 8$$ so $9^{k+1}-8(k+1)-1$ is divisible by 8.

What? We didn't use the induction hypothesis? No matter -- the conclusion is no less true for that.

---

Alternatively, without modular arithmetic: By the binomial theorem
$$ 9^{k+1} = (1+8)^{k+1} = \binom{k+1}0 1^{k+1}8^0 + (\text{terms all involving factors of }8) = 1 + 8c$$
for some $c$. Therefore $$9^{k+1}-8(k+1)-1 = 1 + 8c - 8(k+1) - 1 = 8(c-k-1) $$
which is clearly divisible by $8$.

Answer (score 1):

By the binomial theorem, $9^{n}=(8+1)^{n}=8^2a+\binom{n}{1}8+1=64a+8n+1$, hence the result.

Comment: Induction appears in the binomial theorem...

Comment: Why show the $\binom n18$ term separately?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, that's what the binomial theorem gives, but perhaps it's too much.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to prove $9^n - 1$ is a multiple of 8. ($8n$ being a multiple of 8, subtracting this from $9^n-1$, we obtain a multiple of 8). Now,
\begin{align*}
(9^{n+1}-1) - (9^n-1) = 9^n(9-1) = 8\cdot 9^n
\end{align*}
and we are through.